# Conditionally add error bars to a ggplot2 using data from the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a dot plot representing two variables from a dataframe (`x_values0`, a character vector and `AF`, numerical):

This is an example dataframe:

```
x_values0 AF  sdPopHetAF

pos1      50     12.3
pos2      4      43.6
pos3      67     20.3
pos4      8     1.2
pos5      36     13.7
pos6      78     24.5
```

```
p<-ggplot(data=chr1, aes(x=x_values0, y=AF))+
    geom_point(aes(col=color), size=2)
```

I am trying to add error bars to the points with AF lower than a value (in this case 95) and higher than a value (in this case 10). My intention is that each error bar shows the value `AF` +- the value of the corresponding row of another variable (`sdPopHetAF`).

In the example above, I would like to add errorbars to pos1, pos3, pos5 and pos6; and error bars should extend, for example, in the case of pos1 from 37.7 to 72.3.

I have tryed the following commands:

1. In the first case, I get the following error and no plot

```
ymin<-function(af, sd){
  if(af > 10 && af < 95){
    af - sd
  } else {NA_real_}
}

ymax<-function(af, sd){
  if(af > 10 && af < 95){
    af + sd
  } else {NA_real_}
}



p + geom_errorbar(aes(y=AF, fun.min = ymin(AF, sdPopHetAF), fun.max = ymax(AF,sdPopHetAF)),width = 0.2)
```

```
Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
! geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin and ymax or xmin and xmax
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fun.min, fun.max
```

In the second case, it plots errro bars to all my dots, and additionally it plots always the same error bars.

```
p + geom_errorbar(ymin = ifelse(AF>10 && AF<95, AF - sdPopHetAF, 0), ymax = ifelse(AF>10 && AF<95, AF + sdPopHetAF, 0),width=0.4)
```

[image]

In the last case, it does not plot errorbars and I get a warning

```
p + stat_summary(fun.min = ymin(AF, sdPopHetAF), fun.max = ymax(AF, sdPopHetAF), geom = "errorbar")
```

[image]

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
Can't convert `fun`, a double vector, to a function.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten I've edited the question and added the information

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using dput, e.g. by running `dput(chr1)` and pasting the output into the body of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
ggplot(chr1, aes(x_values0, AF)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(data = subset(chr1, AF > 10, AF < 95),
                aes(ymin = AF - sdPopHetAF,
                    ymax = AF + sdPopHetAF))
```

[image]

Data:

```
chr1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         x_values0 = c("pos1", "pos2", "pos3", "pos4", "pos5", "pos6"),
                AF = c(50L, 4L, 67L, 8L, 36L, 78L),
        sdPopHetAF = c(12.3, 43.6, 20.3, 1.2, 13.7, 24.5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to subset the `data` that is supplied to the `geom_errorbar()` layer:

```r
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- tibble::tibble(
  x = factor(1:10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  ymin = y - .2,
  ymax = y + .2
)

ggplot(dat) + 
  aes(x = x, y = y, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(
    data = dplyr::filter(dat, y < 0),
    width = 0
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>